# Tuples of functions (with different domains and codomains)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I just realized I do not have an answer to the following very (very!) basic question.

Consider the following functions

\begin{align*}
f : \ & A \to C \\
g : \ & B \to D \\
h : \ & B' \to D' \\
\end{align*}

where $A, B, B', C, D, D'$ are arbitrary sets (without a particular relation). Is the following object

\begin{equation*}
F \triangleq (f, g, h) : A \times B \times B' \to C \times D \times D'
\end{equation*}

well-defined? Does the notation actually makes any sense?

To provide an example based on really basic math (to fix ideas), could we have

\begin{align*}
f : \ & \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} \\
g : \ & \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \\
h : \ & \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \\
\end{align*}

with $f (x,y) \triangleq x+y$, $g ( x, y, z) \triangleq (x, y+z)$, and $h (x) \triangleq -x$ with

\begin{equation*}
F \triangleq (f, g, h) : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}?
\end{equation*}

Also, shouldn't we write then $F : \mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ (that somewhat looks weird to me)?

Going "category theory", if $A, B, B', C, D, D'$ are arbitrary objects of a category, is $F$ defined above well-defined and could we write a diagram where on the upper line we have $A \times B \times B$, on the lower line we have $C \times D \times D'$, and in the middle we have *three* arrows (one from $A$ to $C$, etc etc)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:** The question comes from the fact that the examples that can be typically found around in basic textbook all have in common that the functions belonging to the tuple all share the same domain (e.g., $F \triangleq (f, g, h) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $f (x, y) = xy$, $g (x, y) = x+y$, and $h (x, y) = x+y^2$), so much so that it is typically pointed out that it is really like working with three functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ bundled together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the following object well-defined?

Yes, on sets you can check it by chasing elements.

The general picture in any category looks like this (you can just add another set there to match your question, but the drawing is more confusing):

[image]

The map in the middle is induced by the universal property of $C\times D$ applied to the maps $f\circ p_A$ and $g\circ p_B$.

**edit:** the situation in the edit is similar but not the same. It is that whenever you have functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to C$, there is a function $F := (f,g):A\to B\times C$ given by $F(a) = (f(a),g(a))$. Yes, this is well defined and yes, the induced map exists in an analogous situation for any category.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just added an edit that points out where the question really comes from. Typically in the literature on basic math, the fact that the $A$ and $B$ in the domains can be wildly different is not addressed at all, but I was thinking in categorical terms when I thought about the fact that it should be possible.

Comment: Actually, if you have in mind a book that does address an example such as the basic one on $\mathbb{R}$ I put in the edit, it would be great. I never saw anything like that.

Comment: I edited to address your edit. I don't have any book in mind, this is just toying with the definition of the cartesian product. Maybe everything becomes clearer if you write down the definition of $A\times B\times B'$ and have fun with it.

Comment: Once more, thanks a lot. Out of curiosity, given the concrete example I write down of $F$, do you find as weird as I do the $F : \mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ notation? But that is exactly what we should have, right?

Comment: I think the best notation would be $F:\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3$, but this is a personal style.

Comment: I agree with you and that's why I find the other notation really peculiar, but – at the same time – it is really what is written there. :)

Comment: @DanielTeixeira It would be better if you didn't use the same notation for the two different ways of making morphisms to a product...